# Would the community be interested in having printable Sci-Fi & Fantasy flyers?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

This has been discussed in a few other Metas (namely [DIY](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371/how-do-you-feel-about-my-site-promotion-ideas) and [Gaming](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2565/would-you-be-interested-in-printable-gaming-se-posters-to-give-out-and-or-put-in)), so click on those links if you want some backstory. If not, here goes!

We would like to provide **printable promotional flyers** for our **community members** to put up **in the places they frequent**, if the places have a space for them. The goal is to **spread the word of Stack Exchange to your peers and your local community**. The flyer would include:

- **the Sci-Fi & Fantasy design** (which is still on the way)
- the site's **URL**
- a brief **description** of what the site is
- perhaps a few **sample question** titles
- a catchy **slogan** (***please, suggest slogans below!*** This site has a ton of great writers, so put your skills to work!)

Another aspect to this flyering program which I just came up with and would like to run by the community, is possibly **putting your Stack Exchange username** on it and declaring you the **"mayor"** (but not the "mayor" because that term is already taken; perhaps **"ambassador"**) **of your area**. As in, the flyer that you put up at your local bookstore would have your name/username on it as the local representative, for people to use if they want to talk to someone about the site. This might even be something like a Big Brother system (again, another term that is already taken) where you would **help this new user ease into the site** and make them feel super welcome. And another idea; you as the local Stack Exchange authority/mayor/leader/etc could probably be given stickers and shirts to give out as well.

What say you, community? Once we get the Sci-Fi & Fantasy design up and running, are printable flyers for local promotions something that interests you? And is the mayor/Big Brother/other term idea interesting?

Answer (score 7):

Wouldn't it be more sensible and effective to try to put up "flyers" on the internet, in places that other scifi nuts hang out?

There are an awful lot of practical issues around flyers in the real world, and I think it'd be much easier to reach people that ...

- are already in front of a computer
- already on the internet
- participating in a related scifi internet site

... rather than random people in the world, at some random physical location.

However, if you have an *event* that a bunch of scifi nuts will be at, I find that **cool stickers** are a lot more interesting and useful and fun than stuff printed on Ye Olde Paper.

(remember magazines? they're like blogs, but printed on dead trees!)

Comment: You have a point about this site and flyers. But what about Math and Physics, SO, etc... I know that if I didn't know about those sites and I saw a poster for Math.Stackexchange.com posted in the Math lab or Math department at school, I'd be all over it ;P

Comment: There are places that the geek population often congregates at, say at the release of a sci-fi movie or big tech companies etc. I tried placing Google ads for the site, and I tell you, it ain't easy.

Comment: Is there a budget for banner ads? We can do scifi-themed banner ads fairly simply.

Comment: I agree that this can be used on the internet, yes. But I don't think we should limit our scope to JUST the internet. Real world communities spring up in these locations. I think that having a presence in these places, with an ambassador in house and ingrained in that community, could lead to actual committed, long term users. I think that new users are more likely to commit if they have a real life peer to discuss Stack Exchange with.

Comment: @brett just a gentle reminder that only 30% of our traffic is from the USA -- these sorts of "do work in the real world" efforts don't scale, and our audience is extremely distributed worldwide.

Comment: I want stickers.

Answer (score 6):

We should have posters that are kind of vintagey with questions like:

- Is Soylent Green really people?
- Is the Force really with me?
- When will my Hogwarts letter arrive?
- Why haven't I regenerated as a ginger?
- What should I do if my friend is possessed by a Goa'uld?
- Is it really a *game* of thrones? Isn't more of a lottery?
- As the hero of my story, does this mean I get the girl?

And other such "gag" questions that wouldn't *really* be on the site but make it clear who our audience is. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Let's run with the Big Brother angle. After all, the term does originate from the classic SF book [1984](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Brother_%28Nineteen_Eighty-Four%29).

We can clone some of the classic posters:

[image]

And otherwise make classic SF and Fantasy references.

Comment: Anyone by chance know what the font on this poster is?

Comment: I couldn't place it on identifont, it came up with FF Netto, but the edges are too rounded on it. ITC Conduit is closer.

Comment: It's pretty close to Haettenschweiler. [Have a look at this thing I did in Freehand](http://i.imgur.com/xlkpS.jpg), the one on the left is the original, the one on the right is editable text. What do you want it to say? "Big Brother reads Scifi/Fantasy at Stack Exchange" is a bit of a mouthful.

Comment: the G and R have tails that aren't in the other Typeface. But it is close too.

Answer (score 1):

I like this idea. I can see these flyers for this (and other SE sites, too) being popular at bookstores and schools.

I know that the Math.SE, Physics.SE, and SO.SE sites would get HUGE boosts in traffic if there were flyers in our Computer Science/Math department at my school.

If a poster/flyer were posted in community areas of my school as well, then I know the geeks would be all over our site.

I'm not a fan of the Big Brother is Watching you slogan, as it seems to make the site into a tyranny, lol.

I think if we could design a poster with retro 50's style sci-fi cover looking art, then it would be a great attractor.

Just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of images based on [DampeS8N's idea](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/743/would-the-community-be-interested-in-having-printable-sci-fi-fantasy-flyers/744#744) of using old sci-fi images. Would be happy to entertain alternate wording, but keep in mind that it has to be very, very short.  These would both have additional text on the back or along the side.

My thought is to promote the network, with a sci-fi feel. (At least for the first one.)

[image: Big Brother reads Stack Exchange]

[image: Where everyone can hear your questions]

Comment: In regards to the second one. Does anyone know the rules about what counts as parody?

Comment: That wouldn't be parody as it's not making a statement about Alien as commentary on anything. It would be considered infringement. From Wikipedia: The Supreme Court of the United States stated that parody "is the use of some elements of a prior author's composition to create a new one that, at least in part, comments on that author's works." Which that doesn't lol.

Comment: OghmaOsiris - Yeah, these are only intended as mockups.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of flyers, it would be great to be able to print greatest questions and include a [QR Code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code) that link to the question, so the peoples interested in the answer would be introduced to the site.

It would be a good way to win a Announcer badge.